# Scala: Can I use -= head to remove an item from a list?

Tags: scala, listbuffer

It appears that using `i -= i.head`does not perform the same function as `i.remove(0)`  on a ListBuffer.  Is that right.  If so why?

Comment: Can you provide an example where the two operations differ? I think they should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

`i -= i.head` returns the modified `ListBuffer`.

`i.remove(0)` returns the element removed from the `ListBuffer`.

The resulting modified `ListBuffer` is the same in either case.